# How can i successfully launch IDEA IntelliJ from the terrminal?

Tags: path

I tried to add the directory of IntelliJ installation to my PATH environment in order to launch it from anywhere using the command: `idea` or `idea.sh`. 
But even if I think the path is added I still can't open IntelliJ from anywhere;
I still have to do `./idea.sh` in the directory called `/bin`.

I used this command:

```bash
PATH=$PATH:~/home/anthony/ideaIC-2022.2.3/idea-IC-222.4345.14/bin
```

and now when I check the PATH using this command: `echo $PATH`
I have this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/anthony/home/anthony/ideaIC-2022.2.3/idea-IC-222.4345.14/bin
```

and every time I try to call: `idea`
I get the return:

```
bash: idea: command not found
```

I thought adding the path to bin would allow me to run IntelliJ ID
EA from anywhere. 
Did I miss something?

I'm using a Linux Debian 11.
for my specs if I do `lscpu` it returns:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      23
Model:                           24
Model name:                      AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/home/anthony/ideaIC-2022.2.3/idea-IC-222.4345.14/bin
```

You specified the `~` which represents the user home directory (in your case /home/anthony) but you also specified your user home directory after `~`.

So the solution here is to remove the `~` from the PATH:

```bash
PATH=$PATH:/home/anthony/ideaIC-2022.2.3/idea-IC-222.4345.14/bin
```

You can remove `/home/anthony` from your path and use `~` or the environment variable `$HOME`:

```bash
PATH=$PATH:~/ideaIC-2022.2.3/idea-IC-222.4345.14/bin
#or
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/ideaIC-2022.2.3/idea-IC-222.4345.14/bin
```

Comment: Thank you vert much it works!

Comment: @Anthony Glad this worked for you! It should be useful if you mark this answer as accepted: [how to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).